# Fade Out/Fade in with animation speed

Tags: jquery

I am working on something and need something on click to fade out, do something and fade in.

I found this code, but i am not sure how where to out time in milliseconds.

```
$(this).animate({
    opacity:'0'
}, function(){
    //Do something 
    $(this).animate({
        opacity:'1'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` jQuery functions and pass the number of milliseconds as first argument:

```
$(this).fadeOut(500, function(){
    //Do something 
    $(this).fadeIn(700);
});
```

Default time is `400`.

...or if you really want to use `animate()` pass the [`duration` option](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$(this).animate({opacity: 0, duration: 500 });
```

Note that `this` can by any jQuery selector (e.g. `".class"`, `"#id"`).

Reference:

> ### `.fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )`
>
> `duration (default: 400)`
>
> Type: Number or String A string or number
>   determining how long the animation will run.
>
> ---
>
> `complete Type: Function()`
>
> A function to call once the animation is complete.

[**Fade out**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) | [**Fade in**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).animate({
  opacity:'0'
}, 1000 , function(){
  //Do something 
  $(this).animate({
    opacity:'1'
  }, 1000);
});
```

Add ',time' after each animate{} function . . .

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

That code doesn't look like what you want... lets break it down.

```
//On click of element
$("IDofElement").click(function() {
    //Fade out something out
    $("#IDofElementFadingOut").fadeOut(300, function() { //Access the callback (millseconds as first arg)
        //Element has faded out, do something!

        //Something has been done, fadeIn!
        $("IDofElementFadingIn").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the fadeIn and fadeOut with a interval in ms

```
$(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
  // do something
  $(this).fadeIn(1000);
});
```